# Cakephp 3 set hidden value of input field to value of other input field

Tags: cakephp, input

Ok here goes I have a little form in cakephp 3

```
<?= $this->Form->create($program, ['type'=>'file']) ?>
    <fieldset>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('title',        ['label' => 'Program Title']);
        echo $this->Form->input('subtitle',     ['label' => 'Subtitle or Short Summary (15 words or less)']);
        echo $this->Form->input('start_date',   ['type'=>'date']);
        echo $this->Form->input('end_date',     ['type'=>'date']);
        echo $this->Form->input('slug', ['type' => 'hidden']);
```

and I would like to set the hidden input form field slug to the same value as the input field title when it get submitted.

Comment: Sounds a bit [**xy-ish**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do that? If you want to generate a slug field from the title, then there are better ways of doing that in the saving process on the server side.

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing it in the controller and not on the form page.

Comment: A better place would be the model, for example in the `beforeSave()` handler, maybe even in a behavior for even more DRYness, there's an example for that [**in the docs**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors.html#creating-a-behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Ended up removing the field from the form and processing it in the controller like this
`$program = $this->Programs->patchEntity($program, $this->request->data);
$program->slug=$program->title;`

I even went as far as to replace space with -, make the text all lower cause and  remove unwanted characters

```
$program->slug = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $program->slug)); 
$remove = array("`","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","+","=","{","}","[","]","|",":",";",",",'"',"<",">",".","/");
$replace   = array("");
$program->slug = str_replace($remove, $replace, $program->slug);
```

Still refining the code but works like a charm

Comment: I think that `Text::slug()` could do the job for you (apart for the lowercase)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to convert a string to slug, I recommend you to [Inflector](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/inflector.html#creating-url-safe-strings)

```
use Cake\Utility\Inflector; // write this at the top

class .. extends ... {

    /* other code */

    public function <your-function> {
         $title    =    $this->request->data['title'];
         $slug     =    Inflector::slug($title); // Converting to slug
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think slug should be set in model using [mutator](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators) method in `Program` entity and `beforeSave` event in `Programs` table class.

Slug should be unique, so if slug is duplicated, additional number should be appended to slug.

In my own CMS i use something like this (code is adapted for your model):

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\Utility\Text;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class Program extends Entity
{
    protected function _setSlug($value = '') {

        $copy = $slug = Text::slug(mb_strtolower($value));
        $table = TableRegistry::get('Programs');
        $i = 1;

        do {
            $result = $table->find('all' , [
                    'conditions' => [
                        'slug' => $copy
                    ]
                ])
            ->first();

            if(!is_null($result)) {
                $copy = $slug.'-'.$i;
                $i++;
            }
        } while(!is_null($result));

        return $copy;
    }
}
```

Method for table

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class ProgramsTable extends Table
{
    public function beforeSave($event, $entity) {
        $entity->slug = $entity->title;
    }
}
```